# Can originalDestination be used as a selector for a dead-letter queue consumer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

I'm trying to consume from a shared dead-letter queue and only want to consume messages created by my application. I'm trying to add a selector on the consumer on the originalDestination property but it is not working. Is there anything I'm missing?

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${dlq}", selector = "originalDestination = 'Consumer.original.VirtualTopic.original'")
    public void onMessageReceived(Message message) {
        log.info(message.getOriginalDestination().toString());
        log.info(message.toString());
    }
```

Comment: As Tim notes in his answer, this isn't possible with ActiveMQ 5.x. However, if you were using ActiveMQ Artemis you'd be able to use a selector on either the `_AMQ_ORIG_ADDRESS` or `_AMQ_ORIG_QUEUE` message properties which the broker adds when it sends a message to a dead letter address.

Answer (score 1):

The property expression selector for JMSDestination will first peek into the originalDestination field so it can work.
The original destination as a string, will have a queue/topic type prefix.

This should work:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${dlq}", selector = "JMSDestination = 'queue://Consumer.original.VirtualTopic.original'")
```

see: https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/filter/PropertyExpression.java#L48

Comment: Excellent insight! Thanks a bunch! Both the comment to the question, and the other answer, is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Since the original destination is not a JMS reserved property like JMSReplyTo etc and is not a message property accessible through the standard message getObjectProperty type methods the selector would not work on that.

Comment: Thanks for that, i'll add a specific ObjectProperty for all of our messages.